# How to use hooks in Handsontable. I need check data before paste

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, handsontable, rhandsontable

I need to check the data before inserting it into the table and if it is not correct, change it and insert it. I'm trying to create a hook with a beforeInsert prefix and describe this logic there, but it doesn't work.

I tried this code for testing, but nothing changes when pasting

```
  hot1.addHook('beforePaste', function(td1, row1, col1, prop1, value1, cellProperties1) {
          if (prop1 === 'cost1') {
                  var cellMeta1 = this.getCellMeta(row, this.propToCol('cost2'));
                  cellMeta1.type = 'text';
            cellMeta1.source = 'hello';
          }
         }
      );
```

Could the problem be that before that I call this hook?

```
hot1.addHook('beforeRenderer', function(td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
            if (prop === 'warehouse') {
               var cellMeta = this.getCellMeta(row, this.propToCol('xWarehouse'));
               cellMeta.readOnly = (value != ' ' && value != '' && value != null) ? true : false;
           }
     }
);
```

How can you check and insert the changed value into the table?
Example:
At input 3 213, insert 3213, just remove the spaces

UPD :

I also tried to use this:

```
            if (prop === 'cost1' && value != '') {
               var cellMeta = this.getCellMeta(row, this.propToCol('cost1'));
               hot1.setDataAtCell(row,col,value);
           }
      });
```

But in this case, my table freezes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the value with afterChange hook.

```
var setter = false;
        hot1.addHook('afterChange', function(changes, src) {
            if (!setter) {
                setter = true;
                    for(let obj of changes){
                    var currentRow = obj[0];
                    var currentValue = obj[3].replace(/\s+/g,'');
                    var currentCol = obj[1].replace(/\s+/g,'');
                    var colNumber = hot1.propToCol(currentCol);
                    hot1.setDataAtCell(currentRow, colNumber, currentValue);
                    }
            } else {
                setter = false;
            }
        });
```

Handsontable will substitute the values ​​of changes and src itself, after which we can pull out the inserted value and change it, and then insert it back